# Converting a character code to char (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, ascii, character, character-codes

I'm able to convert a character to its corresponding character/ASCII code using "Asc(CHAR)". What can I use to convert this returned integer back to its original character form?

Comment: Note: `Asc` is not for ASCII precisely but it is sufficient for ASCII. It is for the user's current default code page/character encoding, which varies from user to user, machine to machine and time to time. **In most cases, you'd want to use a fixed character encoding**. VB4/5/6/A/Script/.NET… use **UTF-16** for string elements. Use `AscW` and `ChrW` for that.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [`Chr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function in VB.NET converts the integer back to the character:

```
Dim i As Integer = Asc("x") ' Convert to ASCII integer.
Dim x As Char = Chr(i)      ' Convert ASCII integer to char.
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the [Chr or ChrW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function, `Chr(charNumber)`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.  This sounds exactly like what I need :D

Answer (score 5):

you can also use

```
Dim intValue as integer = 65  ' letter A for instance
Dim strValue As String = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(intValue)
```

this doesn't requirement Microsoft.VisualBasic reference

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Chr(int) function

Answer (score 0):

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim n, n1, sum, rm, cnt As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ")
    n = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    n1 = n
    sum = 0
    cnt = n1.ToString.Length - 1
    While n1 <> 0
        rm = n1 Mod 10
        sum = sum + rm * CInt(Math.Pow(10, cnt))
        cnt = cnt - 1
        n1 = n1  10
    End While
    If n = sum Then
        Console.WriteLine("Number is Palindrom")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Number is Palindrom")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Hi, this question was correctly answered in 2011, about 12 years ago. 
While it is usually appreciated to get more answers to the same question, in this case I don't think it is necessary as the precedent solution was exhaustive and precise.